# Clickable divs in Fullscreen Panning HTML5 Video

Tags: html5-video

I am looking for a way to make a panning fullscreen HTML5 video clickable. I want different parts (divs) in the video to follow and stay in place when panning up/down/right or left. Is this even possible?

Best,
Sebastian